# ¿Cómo agregar prefijo a firma de documento XML en C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Desarrollo una aplicación donde firmo un documento XML digitalmente, pero no sé cómo hacer para agregar el Prefijo (xs) a los nodos que genera la firma.

```
<xs:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
```

Mi Código:

```
 private string  FirmaXadesEPES(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate,string path)
    {
        error = string.Empty;
        idFirma = IdSignature();
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        string URI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#";
        try
        {
            signedXml.Signature.Id = "Id-" + idFirma;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
            signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
            keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            //Reference 1
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Id = "r-id-" + idFirma;
            reference.Type = "";
            reference.Uri = "";
            XmlDsigXPathTransform XPathTransform = CreateXPathTransform("//. | //@* | //namespace::*", xmlDoc);
            reference.AddTransform(XPathTransform);
            reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);
            //Reference 2
            Reference reference2 = new Reference();
            reference2.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
            reference2.Uri = "";
            reference2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
            reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(reference2);
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
            bool checkSign = signedXml.CheckSignature();

        } catch (Exception ex) { error = ex.ToString(); }

        xmlDoc.Save(path);
        return error;
    }
```

Firma Generada:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Id-37d3fd17-b0f9-48f0-add9-75a52bb9e83c-59880">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <Reference Id="r-id-37d3fd17-b0f9-48f0-add9-75a52bb9e83c-59880" URI="">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
          <XPath>//. | //@* | //namespace::*</XPath>
        </Transform>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <DigestValue>HiOIkatoMGOfHDeUaCFmeWGrYOhHtkItSfRwvc/z5Vo=</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
    <Reference URI="" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <DigestValue>HiOIkatoMGOfHDeUaCFmeWGrYOhHtkItSfRwvc/z5Vo=</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>P3ElvXAHH1gXbcmiYCyl2OERHeeKOwOER7MFcBHRaYc47rhPmJQl99kiCo4kvXTEEonRVcNYe6jLSFy8bmXxlrLmQ4O5ju/7IOtZqPIcJpOvGQjKlCFw/o3lczynSuSR1sIGWiKe33wV4rahfc5N5dO8PVMSTAz2GgCrDFrVSAg7i4VmAyWoS45qrtgLwh+tIaX8Oc6zSwsiMbJUZ+k9GYFiO9FERoB5ww3AJenylL8wDo4wmGvaBuBjDU0+mgZyeutkgHA7Xge3MQ0QuuGm4FRtYR4itqGq1rnilHmhOxtvqyeNdipg5WKKhuQM55m2eQbdjVFPzC9nJTpIoW7X5g==</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
      <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregue este Metodo  AgregarPrefijo(XmlNodet n) el cual recibe como parametro el nodo de la firma :

```
private void AgregaPrefijo(XmlNode n)
    {
            string[] nodos = { ELEMENTOS A LOS QUE QUIERO AGREGARLE EL PRFIJO};
            int reference = 0;
            try
            {
                foreach (XmlElement item in n.Cast<XmlNode>().Where(e => e.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
                {
                    string nombre = item.Name;
                    if (nodos.Contains (nombre))
                    {
                        item.Prefix = "ds";
                        if (item.HasChildNodes)
                        {
                            AgregaPrefijo(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex.ToString();
            }
        }

 private string  FirmaXadesEPES(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate,string path)
    {
        error = string.Empty;
        idFirma = IdSignature();
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        string URI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#";
        try
        {
            signedXml.Signature.Id = "Id-" + idFirma;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
            signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
            keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            //Reference 1
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Id = "r-id-" + idFirma;
            reference.Type = "";
            reference.Uri = "";
            XmlDsigXPathTransform XPathTransform = CreateXPathTransform("//. | //@* | //namespace::*", xmlDoc);
            reference.AddTransform(XPathTransform);
            reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);
            //Reference 2
            Reference reference2 = new Reference();
            reference2.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
            reference2.Uri = "";
            reference2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
            reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(reference2);
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

               XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
            xmlDigitalSignature.Prefix = "ds";
            **AgregaPrefijo(xmlDigitalSignature);**
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
            bool checkSign = signedXml.CheckSignature();

        } catch (Exception ex) { error = ex.ToString(); }

        xmlDoc.Save(path);
        return error;
    }
```

y antes de guardar el documento  en el metodo FirmaXadesEPES()  agrego estas lineas para Invocarlo

```
 xmlDigitalSignature.Prefix = "ds";
        AgregaPrefijo(xmlDigitalSignature);
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando te refieres a que le coloques un prefijo a los nodos es crear un archivo de esquema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
 targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="Signature">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="SignedInfo">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="CanonicalizationMethod">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required" 
     />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="SignatureMethod">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required" 
    />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Reference">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Transforms">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Transform">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:element name="XPath" type="xs:string" />
                          </xs:sequence>
                          <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" 
        use="required" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DigestMethod">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" 
       use="required" />
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DigestValue" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
              <xs:attribute name="URI" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SignatureValue" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="KeyInfo">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="X509Data">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="X509Certificate" 
     type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Es modificar su método `FirmaXadesEPES` y que considere el prefijo.

Comment: Si construyo un archivo de esquema debo serializar ese archivo en una clase y la verdad no es lo que nesecito, pero creo que puedo agregar NameSpace para que esos nodos obtengan el prefijo implicitamente ...@Davilio sabes como hacerlo ??

Answer (score 0):

No se si es a esto que te refieres pero yo agrego esto en mis etiquetas xml
por Ej.

```
XmlElement oSignature;
string pNamespacePrefix = "ds";

// Registrar el Namespace
oNamespaces.AddNamespace(pNamespacePrefix, SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
var oNamespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);

oSignature = xmlDocument.CreateElement(pNamespacePrefix, "Signature", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
```

Comment: Ok...Pero no se como agregar el prefijo... por que si te fijas todos los nodos son agregados por esta linea SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc); no se donde agregar tu codigo..

Comment: //Continuando...
// Registrar el Namespace

oNamespaces.AddNamespace(pNamespacePrefix,SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);